# Scalar extension of integral extension is integral.

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A$ be an  $R$-algebra which is integral over $R$ and $f:R\rightarrow S$ a ring homomorphism. Show that the scalar extensions $S\otimes _RA$ is integral over $A$.

Can you someone give any hint?

Comment: Should be over $S$. Otherwise, take any $R=A$ and $S$ not integral over $A$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $s_i \in S$ be generators for $S$ over $R$. By assumption each of the $s_i$ satisfies a monic equation $f_i$ over $R$. But then the elements $s_i \otimes 1 \in S\otimes _RA$ generate $S\otimes _RA$ over $A$ AND satisfy the corresponding polynomial eq. $f^A_i$ over $A$, so $S\otimes _RA$ is integral over $A$.

Comment: Good idea, but you got $S$ and $A$ switched up.

Comment: Yes, the S and A are interchanged.

Comment: @Riquelme Why should there be finitely many generators of A over R?

Comment: @Riquelme Also, the tensors of the form $a\oplus 1$ are integral over $S$. How do we conclude for a finite linear combination of those tesnors are also integral?

Comment: @Babai They don’t assume finiteness, and it’s ‘well known’ that integral closure is a ring. In other words, the product or sum of elements integral over a base ring is again integral over the base ring